# PDO While loop only gets the last data

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to display a nested json as seen in this picture

[JSON Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxin0.png)

However it only gets the last data. I am sure that the 1st id has a data. Please see the code below

```
<?php

    include 'conn2.php';  
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $passwd);


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL sp_foods_display();");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bindColumn('bar_name',$bar_name);
    $stmt->bindColumn('address',$address);
    $stmt->bindColumn('id',$post_id);

    $response = array();
    $result   = array();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
        $temp["bar_name"]     = $bar_name;
        $temp["address"]      = $address;
        $temp["item_details"] = getItem($post_id);
        array_push($result, $temp);
    }
    
    $response["result"] = $result;
    
    echo "<pre>" . json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "</pre>";  

    function getItem($id) {
        global $pdo;

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM fct_menu_foods WHERE post_id = :cur_post_id ORDER BY id ASC");
        $stmt->bindParam(":cur_post_id",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $food_details = array();

        $stmt->bindColumn('food_name',$food_name);
        $stmt->bindColumn('price',$price);
        $stmt->bindColumn('img_name',$img_name);

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
            $temp = array();
            $temp["food_name"] = $food_name;
            $temp["price"]     = $price;
            $temp["img_name"]  = $img_name;
            array_push($food_details, $temp);
        }

        return $food_details;
    }
?>
```

my target output is to display all data in nested.

Comment: You missed a `$temp = array();` in the first loop.

Comment: @Syscall i tried it but it still do the same thing. Tried to display error and it gave me unbuffered query

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. My bad. You have to `closeCursor();` for every query and use `fetchAll` for getting the data.